# Search for a field followed by the specified character in Microsoft Word

Tags: search, ms-word, field

I am trying to change format of all REF fields surrounded by square brackets, such as "[{REF ...  \h \t}]". My approach is to search and select all the target fields and then apply format change command, for example Highlight.
A attempt search "[\d" Word delivers selected only the left part of the field, but if I search "\d]" then Word finds nothing.
Is there a way to do such search via GUI or VBA?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., SuperUser, MS Answers).

Comment: Can I edit the original question to fit to to programming domain, please?

Comment: By all means - if indeed you require a programming solution rather than one that is just as easily done through the GUI.

Comment: Can this be accomplished via VBA?

Comment: Yes, but if you know what's in the field, you can do it quite simply via the GUI. No VBA required. For example, to Find a plain PAGE field, you could use: [^19  PAGE ^21].

Comment: The syntax [^19 PAGE ^21] seems to work well only with simple one-word fields such as PAGE, NUMPAGES, etc. My field has the following form: {REF  _Ref117325874 \h \t}, where _Ref... may vary. How do I search these complex fields?

Comment: The approach one might take really depends on what you're trying to achieve - which you've told us nothing about

Comment: I refined my goal in the original post. In fact I want change text format.

Comment: Except for the \t switch - which only suppresses non-delimiter or non-numerical text when used in conjunction with the \n, \r, or \w switch (none of which your field code representation contains) - nothing in your edited original post refers to the text format. As it stands, your \t switch does nothing.

Comment: I added the details to the original post. The question is not about the switches, but about selection of specified field along with "[" and "]" characters surround them.

Comment: I see nothing in your edited post that tells us anything about what you're trying to achieve. Surely, selecting content is for a purpose???

Comment: Selecting content is for a purpose. How can I approach this task?